# Inequality with two real variables, tried re-writing it as sum of squared parenthesis

Tags: inequality

For $a, b ∈ R$ prove the following inequality:
$12a^2 + 36ab + 36b^2 + 7 \geq 18a + 24b$

I suppose it has something to do with squared numbers being positive, so I've tried re-writing the inequality in a couple of ways so that I get squared parenthesis.
But I always get stuck at something like:
$2[(3a+3b)^2] + 7 \geq 6(a^2 + b^2 +3a + 4b)$.

Comment: See https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1566556p9598417 on AoPS.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that it is completing the square

The matrix identity $Q^T DQ = H$    below reads:
$$  12 \left( x + \frac{3y}{2}  - \frac{3}{4} \right)^2 + 9  \left(  y +\frac{1}{6}   \right)^2  = 12 x^2 +36xy+36y^2 + 7 - 18x - 24 y $$

Algorithm discussed at [reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
12 & 18 &  - 9 \\ 
18 & 36 &  - 12 \\ 
 - 9 &  - 12 & 7 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
12 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 9 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
12 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 9 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
12 & 18 &  - 9 \\ 
18 & 36 &  - 12 \\ 
 - 9 &  - 12 & 7 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$